No hay conexión entre servicios en k8s
Hola tengo dos pods corriendo correctamente sin ningún error alguno, uno es el front-end y el otro el back-end. Al hacer el curl desde el pod del front-end no puede encontrar el servicio del back-end, pero cuando hago el curl desde el back al front se conecta correctamente.
Cuando accedo desde el navegador al front, me muestra error desconocido status:0, hacía la base de datos que se encuentra en mongodb, y que es accesible por medio de una url que permite la entrada a toda ip.
Ambos servicios tienen external ip, y diferentes puertos asignados. Alguien sabe qué puede estar fallando? Muchas gracias.
